# Add symbols like % or $ to ggplot axis

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to replicate a scatterplot. the y- axis values are percentages, while the y axis values are dollar amounts. For this reason, I'd like the "%" and "$" symbols showing on every axis break. I'm not sure how to add them. This is my code for that part:

```
scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0, 10000), breaks = c(0, 50, 100, 200, 500, 1000, 2000, 10000)) +
scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 10), breaks = c(0.2, 0.5, 1, 2, 5, 10))
```

thankful for any insights!

Comment: you can use _labels_  in _scale..._ and define your axis labels.

Comment: Or you use the _scales_ - package as shown below.

Answer (score 1):

With the *scales* - package you can add dollar or percent signs like so.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)

x <- seq(0, 10000, 1000)
y <- seq(0,10, 1)
df <- data.frame(x,y)


ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_line() +
  scale_x_continuous(labels = scales::dollar_format())
```

[image]